# GNUPlot if statement on plot

Tags: csv, if-statement, plot, gnuplot

I've a csv data file like this:

```
Sensor1;value;iteration
Sensor2;value;iteration
Sensor2;value;iteration
Sensor1;value;iteration
Sensor2;value;iteration
```

Can I plot two different lines in base of my 1st col value? one for Sensor1 and another for Sensor2 in same plot.
Now I plot all data as follow:

```
set terminal jpeg
set output 'testimage.jpeg'
set   autoscale                        # scale axes automatically
unset log                              # remove any log-scaling
unset label                            # remove any previous labels
set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
set ytic auto                          # set ytics automatically
set datafile separator ";"
set xrange [1:10000]
set yrange [3000:5000]
plot "result_test_day_1.csv" using 5:3:(stringcolumn(1) eq "Sensor1"? $2:1/0) title "a" lc rgb "blue" with lines
plot "result_test_day_1.csv" using 5:3:(stringcolumn(1) eq "Sensor2"? $2:1/0) title "b" lc rgb "red" with lines
```

Comment: you should use just one `plot` command: `plot "result_test_day_1.csv" using 5:3:(stringcolumn(1) eq "Sensor1"? $2:1/0) title "a" lc rgb "blue" with lines, "" using 5:3:(stringcolumn(1) eq "Sensor2"? $2:1/0) title "b" lc rgb "red" with lines`

Comment: ok it seems work ty